# Hibernate L2 Caching for many-to-one associations

Tags: hibernate, second-level-cache, many-to-one

I am somewhat new to hibernate and am attempting to implement second level caching using ehCache.  I am running into a problem when attempting to use the L2 cache to retrieve a many-to-one association.  The association mapping in my foo.hbm.xml file looks like:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.Foo" table="FOO" >
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="FOO_ID" precision="11" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="bar" class="com.test.Bar" >
            <cache usage="read-only" />
            <column name="BAR_TY" not-null="true" />
            <column name="BAR_VAL" length="4" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

(This is a very shortened/modified version of my actual hbm.xml file, hopefully no errors in it)

Note that I am only caching "bar", not "foo".  However when I run a unit test with this mapping I get the following error:

SEVERE: Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(40) The content of element type "many-to-one" must match "(meta*,(column|formula)*)".

When I take out  it works fine, just no L2 caching.
Is it simply that the many-to-one relationship doesn't support caching?  And if so, any suggestions on how to get around this?

FYI I have another unit test that reads "bar" directly (i.e. not through an association) and it works correctly - the 2nd time I get a "bar" it gets it from the L2 cache, so I'm fairly confident I have the rest of the configuration done correctly.  And so sorry, still in the stone ages at work so no annotations etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving definition of `bar` into another, separate `.hbm.xml` and only referencing it from `foo`?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is malformed. It is illegal node `<cache>` inside `<many-to-one>`.
See [**hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd**](http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd). Declaration on `many-to-one` element:

```
<!ELEMENT many-to-one (meta*,(column|formula)*)>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one class CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one entity-name CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one not-null (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one unique (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one unique-key CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one index CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one cascade CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one outer-join (true|false|auto) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one fetch (join|select) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one update (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one insert (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one optimistic-lock (true|false) "true">  
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one foreign-key CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one property-ref CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one formula CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one lazy (false|proxy|no-proxy) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one not-found (exception|ignore) "exception">
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-one embed-xml (true|false) "true">
```

Cache element can be placed on class level:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.Foo" table="FOO" >
        <cache usage="read-only" />
        <id name="id" type="long">
```

or for collections like `set`, `map`, `bag` etc.